# Is [crowd] needed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[crowd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crowd) is undefined.  It has one question which never received an answer.  The question appears to be about basic functionality which would seem to indicate that there is not much familiarity with it among this audience.  I surmise from the question that Crowd is a product from Atlassian.  There is an existing [atlassian](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) tag with four questions, including this one.  Is a separate [crowd] tag needed?

Answer (score 2):

Both [atlassian](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atlassian) and [crowd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crowd) are horrible tags. The question you cite should be tagged [atlassian-crowd](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/atlassian-crowd) and it's fine to stay IMO.